# Rails: Options for build bundler gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundler

I have a gem, that must be build with some options.

```
gem install pg --with-pg-include=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.0/include/ --with-pg-lib=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.0/lib/
```

Can I include this options in the Gemfile? In my Gemfile the `pg` command is

```
gem "pg", "0.12.2"
```

I want to provide some options after the version number.

thx,
tux

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for: http://gembundler.com/man/bundle-config.1.html

Comment: Fixed Link: http://gembundler.com/v1.3/bundle_config.html

Comment: NOTE: The links in the above comments now forward to the home page of the blog.

Comment: Updated link: https://bundler.io/v2.3/man/bundle-config.1.html

Comment: (note that it's `bundle config set` now rather than just `bundle config`)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is the relevant text from the link posted in comments already:

> **BUILD OPTIONS**
>
> You can use `bundle config` to give bundler the flags to pass to the gem installer every time bundler tries to install a particular gem.
>
> A very common example, the `mysql` gem, requires Snow Leopard users to pass configuration flags to `gem install` to specify where to find the `mysql_config` executable.

```
gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```

> Since the specific location of that executable can change from machine to machine, you can specify these flags on a per-machine basis.

```
bundle config build.mysql --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```

> After running this command, every time bundler needs to install the `mysql` gem, it will pass along the flags you specified.

Here is another example of custom build options, in this case specifying a specific source to download from other than rubygems:

`bundle config build.popen4 --source http://gemcutter.org`