# Installing mysql2 on Ruby on Rails with Gem

Tags: mysql, ruby, runtime-error

i'm trying install mysql2 on ruby on rails with gem but, i'm getting this error:

i'm using gem version 2.4.2 and ruby 2.1.4. someone know how to fix it?

```
 gem.bat : ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
Em linha:1 caractere:4
+ gem <<<<  install mysql2
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (ERROR:  Error installing                            mysql2::String)         [],    RemoteException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

C:/Ruby21/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20141107-7440-10fbirr.rb extconf.rb
checking for ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes
checking for rb_intern3()... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

Comment: Which OS you are using?

Comment: @TusharBhaware Windows, obviously :) Look at the path in the error log.

Comment: WINDOWS 7 ULTIMATE SP1

Answer (score 0):

The [`mysql2` gem's GitHub page](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2) suggests this:

> ## Windows
>
> First, make sure you have the DevKit installed
>   (http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/) and its variables are loaded by
>   running devkit\devktvars.bat .
>
> Next, you need a MySQL library to link against. If you have MySQL
>   loaded on your development machine, you can use that. If not, you will
>   need to either copy the MySQL directory from your server, or else
>   obtain a copy of the MySQL C connector:
>   http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/
>
> If you're using the connector, I recommend just getting the .zip file
>   and unzipping it someplace convenient.
>
> Now you can install mysql2. You must use the `--with-mysql-dir` option
>   to tell gem where your MySQL library files are. For example, if you
>   unzipped the connector to `c:\mysql-connector-c-6.1.1-win32` you would
>   install the gem like this:
>
> ```
> gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-dir=c:\mysql-connector-c-6.1.1-win32
> ```
>
> Finally, you must copy `libmysql.dll` from the lib subdirectory of your MySQL or MySQL
>   connector directory into your ruby\bin directory. In the above
>   example, libmysql.dll would be located at
>   c:\mysql-connector-c-6.1.1-win32\lib .

I would, however, switch to a Linux-based virtual machine. There are several reasons for this:

- Many gems just don't work on Windows or require a rather complicated setup (like above)
- You will likely **never** deploy your app to Windows in production, matching environments help track down possible issues easier
- You can use RVM and compile newest Rubies as they are released

Comment: It specifically says it can't find `mysql_query` function, that means it can't find MySQL connector source files. Update the question with the results of what **exactly** you did just now.

Comment: works fine. but when i run 'bundle install' at app folder. return: make sure that 'gem install mysql2 -v "0.3.16"'succeds before bundling.

Comment: This (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9166146/rails-options-for-build-bundler-gemfile) should help with passing these to `bundler`.